# Kendo grid row selection change event?

Tags: click, kendo-ui, html

I've couple of questions..

1. I'm using Kendo grid and would like to know if it is feasible to fire an event at the document level when a row selection is changed.

   Basically, when a row selection is changed, I want to fire an event and this is done at the global level without depending on the gridID.

   Example:

   $('tr.k-state-selected').parents('tbody').live('change', function (e) {
               alert("onchange");
           });
       }

   But the above example do not work. I do not have any other classes defined on the grid/ body/ gridRow.
2. How can I fire a click event using the span class on the kendo window (pop-up)

   I've tried below code but that doesn't work

   ```
       $('span.k-icon.k-i-close').parents('a').click(function (e) {
           alert("clicked!");
       });
   ```

Do I need to include any adidtional classes for recognizing the kendo window ?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

You are looking for [`change`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-change) event.

You might also been interested on taking a look into this [demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/events.html) showing different `grid` events.

Comment: One thing that I find particularly annoying, is that the 'change' event only fires when selections 'changes' to an item, and does not fire when selection changes 'from' an item. Example being when you select an item, then re-order results, it loses selection but no event is fired to imply selection has changed.

Comment: @JoshMc You should probably send your feedback to Telerik's Customer Voice so they can consider including it in the next release.

Comment: @JoshMc You are right this could be an issue. As a workaround I recommend force to have always a selected row, I mean select the first row programmatically after load, and then all events what potentially loses the selected row